# SonarQube exception trying to render system info

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

I was trying to look at the system information on my local SonarQube system today. Nothing was displayed, so I checked the logs that are linked from the page. I found the output below. I haven't changed my sonar installation in months so I don't know how something would have changed, and I believe that I've been to the system info page since the last upgrade.

Any ideas what's wrong or how to fix it?

```
2018.04.19 10:14:33 ERROR web[rails] 
Java::JavaLang::InternalError (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el6_9.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar):
  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1040)
  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:239)
  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2640)
  java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
  java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
  java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419)
  java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
  java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
  java.util.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:1819)
  java.util.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:1815)
  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  java.util.logging.Logger.findSystemResourceBundle(Logger.java:1815)
  java.util.logging.Logger.findResourceBundle(Logger.java:1867)
  java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1941)
  java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380)
  java.util.logging.LogManager$SystemLoggerContext.demandLogger(LogManager.java:925)
  java.util.logging.LogManager.demandSystemLogger(LogManager.java:581)
  java.util.logging.Logger.getPlatformLogger(Logger.java:576)
  java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl.getLogger(LoggingProxyImpl.java:41)
  sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport.getLogger(LoggingSupport.java:100)
  sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.<init>(PlatformLogger.java:602)
  sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.<init>(PlatformLogger.java:597)
  sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.<init>(PlatformLogger.java:239)
  sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.getLogger(PlatformLogger.java:198)
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.<clinit>(HttpURLConnection.java:431)
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
  java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:633)
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:617)
  org.sonar.server.platform.monitoring.ProcessSystemInfoClient.connect(ProcessSystemInfoClient.java:53)
  org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.writeJson(InfoAction.java:81)
  org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.handle(InfoAction.java:66)
  org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:107)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425)
  org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292)
  org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
  rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D01792011778.__file__(app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:34)
  rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D01792011778.__file__(app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
  org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778.block_0$RUBY$__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68)
  rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
  rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1792011778.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E01792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E01792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81)
  org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
  org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:103)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551792011778.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:50)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:233)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:71)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:105)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
  org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:46)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:217)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:66)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_D1BAE9F2F7D6D00DAEDE9A175F15297655D718711792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_D1BAE9F2F7D6D00DAEDE9A175F15297655D718711792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$call_8944B8D4A6D3AF4F57DE7885AE3EA09ADFDAED2A1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$call_8944B8D4A6D3AF4F57DE7885AE3EA09ADFDAED2A1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::RouteSet$$call_426E45DA86B30E16B94E5379DB9F140F78AE4BF41792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::RouteSet$$call_426E45DA86B30E16B94E5379DB9F140F78AE4BF41792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791792011778.chained_1_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791792011778.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$_call_CD38443163AC875A33B6E9F44AC41E096715B2081792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$_call_CD38443163AC875A33B6E9F44AC41E096715B2081792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
  org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
  org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
  org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
  org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
  org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
  org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224)
  org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011792011778.block_0$RUBY$__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29)
  rubyjit$ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache$$cache_A633D695A7F60465017E9EF9D11E22D24BBB2F4C1792011778.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache$$cache_A633D695A7F60465017E9EF9D11E22D24BBB2F4C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache$$cache_A633D695A7F60465017E9EF9D11E22D24BBB2F4C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:149)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache::ClassMethods$$cache_F67A1FFCC8AF52449A8884B5FC24C1FD70A7AFD21792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache::ClassMethods$$cache_F67A1FFCC8AF52449A8884B5FC24C1FD70A7AFD21792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement$$call_90D2EFA9453A4B4B189AB976C186F4E8E3F4ECFD1792011778.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement$$call_90D2EFA9453A4B4B189AB976C186F4E8E3F4ECFD1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb)
  rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement$$call_90D2EFA9453A4B4B189AB976C186F4E8E3F4ECFD1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb)
  ... More trace deleted to get under the 30K character limit.   

2018.04.19 10:14:34 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/api/system/info
undefined method `clean_message' for #<Java::JavaLang::InternalError:0x2b81b13a>
On line #7 of gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb

4:     in <%=h request.parameters['controller'].humanize %>Controller<% if request.parameters['action'] %>#<%=h request.parameters['action'] %><% end %>
5:   <% end %>
6: </h1>
7: <pre><%=h @exception.clean_message %></pre>
8: 
9: <%= render :file => @rescues_path["rescues/_trace.erb"] %>
10: 

gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:7
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:133:in `rescue_action_locally'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:152:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:73:in `rescue_action'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:162:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
config/environment.rb:67:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
file:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
file:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
file:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
file:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Comment: Update the jdk plugin for sonar, it's possible you updated the java version or introduced new changes in your code that would need a new version of sonar plugins, I would say update the sonar to latest and try again.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi I think the system info page is where I would update the plugins. Is there a way to do it by reconfiguring things using a command line? Hopefully GAnn-SonarSourceTeam or Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam or someone from SQ will catch this.

Comment: I would suggest do it from Update Center to Install plugins automatically, from the SonarQube UI. And later you can validate the plugin version in sonarqube/extenstions/plugins folder.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Update Center seems to be broken too. No matter which of the four boxes I click I get a little red popup that says "null", and there is nothing displayed below those boxes. nothing installed, or available or anything. Something's seriously wrong.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64

Comment: Right. It's in your error message.

Comment: @G.Ann I noticed that the version in the error and the version I found were different. So I ran alternatives java and javac to refresh things and the clrdata error disappeared. But please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985969/sonarqube-wont-display-system-info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had upgraded the JDK version sometime ago and something got messed up. I ran alternatives java, java and re-selected the current option and that specific problem seems to be resolved.

But now see: [SonarQube won't display System Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985969/sonarqube-wont-display-system-info).

Comment: Thanks to @G.Ann for drawing my attention to the specifics of the version.